# Can a Ncurses Form field be "pad-less"?

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm using Ncurses form for a c application.
My problem is that, when i read the fields retrieved from a form, they are padded with spaces, while i need to have the "correct" string (for example, i can't trim trailing spaces in a password field).
There is an elegant way to do this, or is there a way to retrieve the lenght, so i can trim it in a second moment at the right char?

Comment: Consider posting the code you wrote.

Comment: It's the normal behaviour, even the example here in Ncurses form library howto https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/forms.html works in the same way. i was searching for a workaround to this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this by maintaining a field-buffer which stores the character string in the format that you want to retrieve).  The demo_forms.c program in ncurses-examples does this.   The [comment](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/361a7549f658c34089571844cc8dd9e860324513/test/demo_forms.c#L162) in the code

```
/*
 * Define each field with an extra one, for reflecting "actual" text.
 */
static FIELD *
make_field(const char *label, int frow, int fcol, int rows, int cols)
{
    FIELD *f = new_field(rows, cols, frow, fcol, o_value, 1);
```

refers to that **`1`** parameter passed to [`new_field`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_field_new.3x.html) (the number of *extra* buffers).

(for the details, you'll have to read the source code and manual pages: tutorials are off-topic here...)

Comment: Thank you, i tried and it works. Now the problem is that if i set the initial buffer of a field with a string with trailing spaces, they will be trimmed, so it is another problem. so... i think i will force the user to not use trailing spaces.